# Fast numpy aggregate function?

Tags: python, numpy

Do you know a pure numpy (i.e. no cython) way to aggregate values of an array into buckets as done in the function below, but without the for loop (for the sake of performance)?

```
import numpy as np

def aggregate(values, buckets, n_buckets):
    aggr = np.empty((n_buckets,))
    for bucket in range(n_buckets):
        mask = (buckets == bucket)
        aggr[bucket] = sum(values[mask]) / np.count_nonzero(mask)
    return aggr

values = np.array( [0, 1, 10, 11, 2, 12], dtype=float)
buckets = np.array([0, 0,  1,  1, 0,  1])
n_buckets = 2
print aggregate(values, buckets, n_buckets)
```

[  1.  11.]